# Disable click event on ajax loaded content of a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable click event on ajax loaded content of a DIV.

```
<div id="left_column">
    <div class="menu">------</div>
    <div class="menu">------</div>
    <div class="small_panel1">------</div>
    <div class="small_panel1">------</div>
</div>
```

I want disable click event from all div inside leftcolumn.

I am trying below code but it is not working :-

```
$("#left_column").children().bind('click', function(){ return false; });
```

Please suggest me what should I use here. Thank in advance

Answer (score 2):

If it's AJAX-loaded content, you need to use event delegation:

```
$("#left_column").on('click', 'div', function(){ return false; });
```

You may also need to cancel clicks on the left column container itself:

```
$("#left_column").on('click', function(){ return false; });
```

Comment: Please be more specific about what content you're loading and what you're trying to prevent.